# How can a deaf player detect where monsters and caves are?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, accessibility

I see all the time that the recommended ways to mine is to dig deep and listen out for the sounds of monsters in caves.

My niece is deaf, and whilst she loves the building aspect of the game, tasks like "finding caves" or "knowing a monster is behind you" are obviously more difficult.

Are there any settings or mods that can be used to give a visual indication that the player is in the vicinity of mobs? Especially something showing the *direction* the sound is coming from.

Comment: It might be an idea to submit a feature request -- using a "rumble" mouse.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure that there is a minimap mod that shows monsters as red dots around the player, I'm unsure of what it is called though.

Comment: In a more general perspective, maybe there exist programs which visualize sound. I imagine taking the left and right border of the screen and displaying a spectrogram (high frequency at the top, low frequency at the bottom) might be useful. Unfortunately I am not aware of any such program though :-/ But there is [interesting research](http://masterthesis.hansvanzutphen.com/) going on...

Comment: @Ender I think you are referring to [Rei's minimap](http://www.minecraftdl.com/rei)

Comment: I had this same problem when my sound card on my PC gave out.

Comment: I wonder if [this](http://www.springerlink.com/content/uv377604u5617x01/?MUD=MP) is any good. Too bad it's merely a scientific publication for access of which one has to pay :-/

Comment: @yx Rei's minimap can not only show you monsters with depth indication, but can also show you caves nearby. Playing Technic with monsters on the minimap makes it very easy for me to avoid/hunt them, so it should be very effective for the OP's niece.

Comment: There have been a great deal of mods that conform to your needs, but all of them are outdated :(

Comment: In the long term, I would suggest petitioning Mojang for more accessibility features.

Comment: And here I never even play with sound on at all.

Comment: Here this makes me wonder, how many games include sound reinterpritation for the deaf. As in how many games have a way to represent 3D sound in a non sound fashion?

Comment: Maybe your niece would like "peaceful mode" in which aggressive mobs don't spawn at all?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Minecraft release 1.9+ you can enable subtitles in the corner of the screen, which show what sounds played in the last ~5 seconds! Each sound subtitle fades away with time, darkening and vanishing in a few seconds. Plus, small arrows indicate which side of the player the sound came from.

---

Or use **commands** (more reliable, but harder):

To be notified when a specific mob is close, put the command below in a normal command block on a slow Redstone clock:

```
/execute @e[type=MobName] ~ ~ ~ execute @a[r=R] ~ ~ ~ say @p Warning: MobName
```

You can change the `MobName` to detect mobs with that name and adjust the radius (`r`) to a value that you want.  But watch out - the command syntax is case-sensitive! Don't put spaces inside the brackets and don't forget to use capital letters in mob names!

**Example**: To get warned when a Zombie is less then 5 blocks away from you, use this:

```
/execute @e[type=Zombie] ~ ~ ~ execute @a[r=5] ~ ~ ~ say @p WARNING: Zombie
```

**Example #2**: To be notified when a cave is somewhere around and when it's close, use this bat detector (I used a higher value of `r`):

```
/execute @e[type=Bat] ~ ~ ~ execute @a[r=16] ~ ~ ~ say @p Cave 20 blocks away!

/execute @e[type=Bat] ~ ~ ~ execute @a[r=8] ~ ~ ~ say @p Cave 10 blocks away!
```

Comment: This is awesome. I wish I had this solution four years ago, but better late than never!

Comment: @victoriah thanks for coming back and accepting this answer, it helps other people who look for the solution.

Answer (score 32):

Most of the monster sounds are low pitch. There are chairs that integrate speakers to let players feel low frequency sounds. You should investigate those.

Comment: While a nifty idea, this doesn't really help with the direction part.

Comment: Unlike subwoofers which are omnidirectional, speaker chairs have drivers in multiple locations. Front/back is difficult to implement, but left/right is trivial, you just put one speaker behind the left shoulder and one behind the right.

Answer (score 32):

The [Captioning API](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1608642-146-caption-api-02-wip-for-the-hearing-impaired/) is a [modloader](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v15-risugamis-mods-updated/) mod that captions the sounds of the world. Some of them are deliberately ambiguous, I only learnt through hearing the noises at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Only thing missing is the direction of the sound.

Answer (score 24):

You could turn off all music and turn the sound volume up. Lay the speakers on their back, put a thin plate on them and put sand on them. Sound vibrations will cause [Chladni Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chladni_patterns#Chladni_plates) (sorry, the [German Wikipedia Article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chladnische_Klangfigur) is more informative here...) to occur, similar to the ones you see in this YouTube video:

With some practice, your niece might learn to differ between the patterns of e.g. Zombie grumbling and water flowing.

Comment: Of course [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zoTKXXNQIU) looks cooler...

Comment: This is an amazing idea

Comment: it is great, low cost, highly adaptable, but then the non-deaf people in the room have to listen to ear-shatteringly loud audio (?). Note also that those patterns were created with a very specific controlled sine wave pattern IIRC.

Comment: @horatio & Ender Thanks :-) I don't know _how_ loud it has to be. I can imagine by using a thin foil or balloon skin instead of plates, or even opening up the speakers and putting the sand directly on the membrane, it won't have to be that loud. Alternatively one could look for a sound driver that converts all output to frequencies outside [human hearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range#Humans) (< 12 Hz or > ~20 kHz). Low frequencies require a bigger surface, increasing the visible pattern resolution as a bonus. Or maybe attach the speakers beneath the table

Comment: Now make a video doing this with minecraft sounds :) Until then, this is absolutely useless as the patterns here are given ample time to transition,  and of specific regular sound waves. But this is a good start

Comment: @ydobonebi Good point, wish I currently had the time to this...

Answer (score 15):

*note: This is still a draft which I plan to expand into more precise instructions*

I'd like to elaborate a bit more on [my previous comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89066/how-can-a-deaf-player-detect-where-monsters-and-caves-are#comment122604_89066), which while also dealing with visualization, is about a software solution instead of [the hardware solution I also posted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89108/88).

The basic idea is displaying a spectrogram together with the (windowed) Minecraft so that the audio visualization helps locating mobs, caves etc. So first some background information [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spectrogram&oldid=497785339):

> A spectrogram is a time-varying spectral representation (forming an
>   image) that shows how the spectral density of a signal varies with
>   time. Also known as spectral waterfalls, sonograms, voiceprints, or
>   voicegrams, spectrograms are used to identify phonetic sounds, to
>   analyse the cries of animals; they were also used in many other fields
>   including music, sonar/radar, speech processing, seismology, etc.
>   The instrument that generates a spectrogram is called a spectrograph.

As an example, here's a spectrogram [of a violin](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Violin_for_spectrogram.ogg):

[image]

Time flows from left to right while the bottom represents lower frequencies and the top the higher ones. It's actually easier to understand in animation, so here's some classical music

(there's also [the infamous Aphex Twin face](http://www.bastwood.com/?page_id=10), see e.g. [here](http://youtu.be/M9xMuPWAZW8?t=5m30s). It's actually [incredible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcBDSoVs42M) what [stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e6LMyRUfAM) one can [do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5favl2Qtx0) with this.)

---

Since the location of objects requires Stereo sound, you need a software that can plot a real time stereo spectrogram. (Ok, maybe a simple spectral analyser may suffice, but in order to compensate for the difficulty of identifying a signal, looking back in time for a second sounds fair) I'll assume you don't want to buy a commercial product for this, and why should you when there's freeware available?

The simplest one I found is called [Spectrogram 5.0](http://www.electronics-lab.com/downloads/pc/003/). It's a tiny download and provides a stereo view, although the resolution is quite raw IMHO. (I'll update this answer if you have trouble with the configuration).

The OpenSource project [Spek](http://spek-project.org/) looks promising but doesn't seem to support live output at the moment, while the [Overtone Analyzer Free Edition](http://www.sygyt.com/en/free-spectrum-analyzer) looks a lot more elaborated but I haven't found a Stereo visualization setting yet. Other programs I have not yet checked are [SFS/RTGRAM](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/rtgram/), [WaveSurfer](http://www.spectrogramsforspeech.com/tutorials-2/wavesurfer-overview/), [Waterfall Spectrum Analyzer](http://www.sethoscope.net/waterfall/).

Finally, there is [Spectrum Lab](http://www.qsl.net/dl4yhf/spectra1.html), which I have used quite some time ago. I don't remember if it supports Stereo, but with the correct settings the results are great...

Comment: This is such a cool answer. Thanks for your thoughts, they were interesting. I'll look into the things you linked! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I'll try and expand this into a step-by-step answer maybe including a short video at some point, but right now I'm unfortunately too low on spare time :-/

Answer (score 13):

Captions/subtitles have been added in the [official *Minecraft* 1.9 release](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.9?cookieSetup=true).

- https://twitter.com/Dinnerbone/status/574967417694216192
- https://twitter.com/Dinnerbone/status/577492733402619904

[image: animated GIF of Minecraft captions/subtitles]

Comment: Well, this is great news. I've bugged dinnerbone about this many times. I'm not deaf, but I suffer from random hearing loss (cronic ear wax leakage). I try to get games and other media (like every YTber I watch) to include subtitles. Somehow I missed this update though....weird.

Answer (score 10):

I wonder if a set of speakers/headphones could be placed/tuned so that she could feel the stereo sound?  If you attempt this, it may be advantageous to swap out the normal sounds of the game for ones that are (lower?) tones that can be more readily felt.  The sound files are in the minecraft folder under resources/sound/sound3/mob.

I honestly, don't know if this would work... It's just the first low-tech thing that came to mind.

Good luck.  Don't dig down. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Use Rei's Minimap mod For Monsters, and X-ray texture pack for finding caves.
X-ray can be annoying, but you can switch it off easily on the menu.

Comment: Rei's Minimap has a mode to show caverns, which is much less disruptive than X-ray.

Answer (score 5):

I realise this question is quite old, but came across it "by accident" and thought this might help.

When I recently installed my ASUS motherboard drivers on a new system, I got the option of installing a program called "Sonic Radar II".

From the [ROG Sonic Radar page](http://rog.asus.com/technology/rog-sound-innovations/sonic-radar/):

> Sonic Radar is and onscreen overlay that visually represents sound
>   activities according to their positional location. It is designed as a
>   gaming aid for pro/am gamers, those hard of hearing or unable to use
>   in-game audio clearly. It does not interfere with game files, nor does
>   it represent anything more than the game engine produces.

The page also contains a video explaining things in more detail.

I haven't tried this with minecraft specifically (or with any other game, for that matter), because for people with normal hearing, it's arguably a bit of a cheat. But for people with hearing disabilities, it might be just the thing...